# Filtering in Laravel using regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to filter products based on query string. My goal is to get products from a collection if it's given, otherwise get every product. Could someone help me what's wrong with the following code?

```
$products = \App\Product::where([
'collection' => (request()->has('collection')) ? request('collection') : '[a-z]+',
'type' => (request()->has('type')) ? request('type') : '[a-z]+'
])->get();
```

PS.: I've also tried with 'regex:/[a-z]+', it's not working...

```
$products = \App\Product::where(['collection' => (request()->has('collection')) ? request('collection') : 'regex:/[a-z]+'])->get();
```

Comment: the where functionality uses a column, operator and value ... the values are literal values, not SQL expressions, functions, columns etc

Comment: In addition to @lagbox comment, try `DB::raw('[a-z]+')`.

Comment: If this is using MySQL you might be able to do `where('collection', 'rlike', '[a-z]+')` or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use `when` eloquent clause, so your where clause for collections will be triggered only when the `request('collection')` exists, same logis applie to type as well.

```
$products = \App\Product::
when(request()->has('collection'), function ($q) {
    return $q->where('collection', request('collection'));
});
->when(request()->has('type'), function ($q) {
    return $q->where('type', request('type'));
})
->get();
```

Or another way if you have your `request` values assigned to a variable something like:

```
    $collection = request('collection');
    $type= request('type');

        $products = \App\Product::
        when(!empty($collection), function ($q) use ($collection) {
            return $q->where('collection', $collection);
        });
        ->when(!empty($type), function ($q) use ($type) {
            return $q->where('type', $type);
        })
        ->get();
```